# how to filter error from bulk xml response ?? using python http post request

Tags: python, http, post

This is my response XML i want to filter only those xml which have error response. Since i am doing bulk post request i want to filet and save the error xml as text i am using http post via python. please  suggest me some help thank you.

```
 <Header> 
    <ResponseHeader>
    <RequestMessageKey>
    <GlobalUUID/>
    <RequestUUID>1618727665.1963067</RequestUUID>
    <ServiceRequestId>BalInq</ServiceRequestId>
    <ServiceId>BalInq</ServiceId>
    <ServiceRequestVersion>1</ServiceRequestVersion>
    <ServiceVersion>1</ServiceVersion>
    <ChannelId>C</ChannelId>
    <OriginatorId>C</OriginatorId>
    <OriginatorInstanceId/>
    <OriginatorVersion/>
    <LanguageId>en_US</LanguageId>
    </RequestMessageKey>
    <ResponseMessageInfo>
    <BankId>9</BankId>
    <TimeZone>GMT+05:30</TimeZone>
    <MessageDateTime>2021-04-18T11:54:14.965</MessageDateTime>
    </ResponseMessageInfo>
    <UBUSTransaction>
    <Id>43845</Id>
    <Status>FAILED</Status>
    </UBUSTransaction>
    <HostTransaction>
    <Id>E0000</Id>
    <Status>FAILURE</Status>
    </HostTransaction>
    <HostParentTransaction>
    <Id>null</Id>
    <Status>null</Status>
    </HostParentTransaction>
    <CustomInfo/>
    </ResponseHeader>
    </Header>
    <Body>
    <Error>
    <FIBusinessException>
    <ErrorDetail><ErrorCode>162</ErrorCode><ErrorDesc>Account does not exist</ErrorDesc><ErrorSource>acct.foracid</ErrorSource><ErrorType>BE</ErrorType></ErrorDetail>
    </FIBusinessException>
    </Error></Body>
    </FIXML>
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far....

Comment: ive tried try except also i am new here but i dont know why it is not writing in file from except part.ive tried everything i could. i really need help.

Comment: tree = ET.fromstring(payload)
for node in tree.iter("Error"):
    print(node)
    for elem in node.iter("Error"):
        if not elem.tag==node.tag:
            print("{}: {}".format(elem.tag, elem.text))